Siesta 5.0 compilation fails with "Deferred-length character component 'message' at (1) is not yet supported" message
I am trying to compile the new siesta 5.0 but the compilation fails right from the start with "Deferred-length character component 'message' at (1) is not yet supported" error message.
The config step is passed successfully and I used the following the command:
cmake -S. -B_build -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/boubacart/SIESTA/siesta/bin -DSIESTA_WITH_MPI=ON -DSIESTA_WITH_ELPA=ON -DSCALAPACK_LIBRARY_DIR=/usr/lib64/openmpi/lib -DSCALAPACK_LIBRARY="-lscalapack"

The compiler is gcc 4.8.5  and gfortran 4.8.5.
However, when I try to build using:
cmake --build _build -j 4

The following errors occur:
=================================================================<br/>
[  0%] Building Fortran object _deps/libfdf-build/CMakeFiles/libfdf-lib.dir/src/prec.F90.o <br/>
[  0%] Building Fortran object _deps/libfdf-build/CMakeFiles/libfdf-lib.dir/src/utils.F90.o <br/>
[  0%] Building Fortran object _deps/mctc-lib-build/CMakeFiles/mctc-lib-lib.dir/src/mctc/env/ accuracy.f90.o <br/>
[  0%] Building Fortran object _deps/xmlf90-build/CMakeFiles/xmlf90-lib.dir/src/wxml/m_wxml_array_str.f90.o <br/>
[  0%] Building Fortran object _deps/libgridxc-build/CMakeFiles/libgridxc-lib.dir/src/alloc.F90.o <br/>
[  0%] Building Fortran object _deps/mctc-lib-build/CMakeFiles/mctc-lib-lib.dir/src/mctc/env/error.f90.o <br/>
/home/boubacart/SIESTA/siesta-5.0.0/_build/_deps/mctc-lib-src/src/mctc/env/error.f90:46.46: <br/>

      character(len=:), allocatable :: message
                                              1
**Error: Deferred-length character component 'message' at (1) is not yet supported** <br/>
/home/boubacart/SIESTA/siesta-5.0.0/_build/_deps/mctc-lib-src/src/mctc/env/error.f90:46.46:

      character(len=:), allocatable :: message
                                              1
**Error: Deferred-length character component 'message' at (1) is not yet supported** <br/>
gmake[2]: *** [_deps/mctc-lib-build/CMakeFiles/mctc-lib-lib.dir/src/mctc/env/error.f90.o] Error 1 <br/>
gmake[1]: *** [_deps/mctc-lib-build/CMakeFiles/mctc-lib-lib.dir/all] Error 2 <br/>
gmake[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs.... <br/>
[  0%] Building Fortran object _deps/libgridxc-build/CMakeFiles/libgridxc-lib.dir/src/precision.F90.o <br/>
[  0%] Building Fortran object _deps/xmlf90-build/CMakeFiles/xmlf90-lib.dir/src/wxml/m_wxml_error.f90.o <br/>
[  0%] Building Fortran object _deps/libgridxc-build/CMakeFiles/libgridxc-lib.dir/src/sys.F90.o <br/>
[  0%] Building Fortran object _deps/xmlf90-build/CMakeFiles/xmlf90-lib.dir/src/wxml/m_wxml_escape.f90.o <br/>
[  0%] Building Fortran object _deps/xmlf90-build/CMakeFiles/xmlf90-lib.dir/src/wxml/m_wxml_text.F90.o <br/>
[  0%] Building Fortran object _deps/xmlf90-build/CMakeFiles/xmlf90-lib.dir/src/dom/m_dom_debug.f90.o <br/>
[  0%] Building Fortran object _deps/libfdf-build/CMakeFiles/libfdf-lib.dir/src/io_fdf.F90.o <br/>
[  0%] Building Fortran object _deps/libfdf-build/CMakeFiles/libfdf-lib.dir/src/legacy_units.F90.o <br/>
[  0%] Building Fortran object _deps/libgridxc-build/CMakeFiles/libgridxc-lib.dir/src/gridxc_config.F90.o <br/>
[  0%] Building Fortran object _deps/libfdf-build/CMakeFiles/libfdf-lib.dir/src/parse.F90.o <br/>
[  0%] Building Fortran object _deps/xmlf90-build/CMakeFiles/xmlf90-lib.dir/src/dom/m_dom_error.f90.o <br/>
[  0%] Building Fortran object _deps/xmlf90-build/CMakeFiles/xmlf90-lib.dir/src/dom/m_dom_strings.f90.o <br/>
[  0%] Building Fortran object _deps/xmlf90-build/CMakeFiles/xmlf90-lib.dir/src/sax/m_sax_debug.f90.o <br/>
[  0%] Building Fortran object _deps/xmlf90-build/CMakeFiles/xmlf90-lib.dir/src/sax/m_sax_buffer.f90.o <br/>
[  0%] Building Fortran object _deps/xmlf90-build/CMakeFiles/xmlf90-lib.dir/src/sax/m_sax_charset.f90.o <br/>
[  1%] Building Fortran object _deps/xmlf90-build/CMakeFiles/xmlf90-lib.dir/src/sax/m_sax_reader.f90.o <br/>
[  1%] Building Fortran object _deps/libgridxc-build/CMakeFiles/libgridxc-lib.dir/src/m_walltime.F90.o <br/>
[  1%] Building Fortran object _deps/xmlf90-build/CMakeFiles/xmlf90-lib.dir/src/xpath/match_tester.f90.o <br/>
[  1%] Building Fortran object _deps/libfdf-build/CMakeFiles/libfdf-lib.dir/src/fdf.F90.o <br/>
[  1%] Building Fortran object _deps/libgridxc-build/CMakeFiles/libgridxc-lib.dir/src/ldaxc.F90.o <br/>
[  1%] Building Fortran object _deps/libgridxc-build/CMakeFiles/libgridxc-lib.dir/src/xc_xwpbe.F90.o <br/>
[  1%] Linking Fortran static library libfdf.a <br/>
[  1%] Building Fortran object _deps/libgridxc-build/CMakeFiles/libgridxc-lib.dir/src/interpolation.F90.o <br/>
[  1%] Built target libfdf-lib <br/>
[  1%] Building Fortran object _deps/libgridxc-build/CMakeFiles/libgridxc-lib.dir/src/bessph.F90.o <br/>
[  1%] Building Fortran object _deps/libgridxc-build/CMakeFiles/libgridxc-lib.dir/src/gridxc_fft_gpfa.F90.o <br/>
[  1%] Building Fortran object _deps/libgridxc-build/CMakeFiles/libgridxc-lib.dir/src/cellsubs.F90.o <br/>
[  1%] Building Fortran object _deps/libgridxc-build/CMakeFiles/libgridxc-lib.dir/src/sorting.F90.o <br/>
[  1%] Building Fortran object _deps/libgridxc-build/CMakeFiles/libgridxc-lib.dir/src/m_io.F90.o <br/>
[  1%] Building Fortran object _deps/libgridxc-build/CMakeFiles/libgridxc-lib.dir/src/am05.F90.o <br/>
[  1%] Building Fortran object _deps/libgridxc-build/CMakeFiles/libgridxc-lib.dir/src/array.F90.o <br/>
[  1%] Building Fortran object _deps/xmlf90-build/CMakeFiles/xmlf90-lib.dir/src/wxml/m_wxml_elstack.f90.o <br/>
[  1%] Building Fortran object _deps/xmlf90-build/CMakeFiles/xmlf90-lib.dir/src/wxml/m_wxml_buffer.f90.o <br/>
[  2%] Building Fortran object _deps/libgridxc-build/CMakeFiles/libgridxc-lib.dir/src/xc_hybrids.F90.o <br/>
[  2%] Building Fortran object _deps/xmlf90-build/CMakeFiles/xmlf90-lib.dir/src/wxml/m_wxml_dictionary.f90.o <br/>
[  2%] Building Fortran object _deps/libgridxc-build/CMakeFiles/libgridxc-lib.dir/src/mesh1d.F90.o <br/>
[  2%] Building Fortran object _deps/xmlf90-build/CMakeFiles/xmlf90-lib.dir/src/dom/m_dom_types.f90.o <br/>
[  2%] Building Fortran object _deps/xmlf90-build/CMakeFiles/xmlf90-lib.dir/src/sax/m_sax_converters.f90.o <br/>
[  2%] Building Fortran object _deps/libgridxc-build/CMakeFiles/libgridxc-lib.dir/src/minvec.F90.o <br/>
[  2%] Building Fortran object _deps/xmlf90-build/CMakeFiles/xmlf90-lib.dir/src/sax/m_sax_dictionary.f90.o <br/>
[  2%] Building Fortran object _deps/libgridxc-build/CMakeFiles/libgridxc-lib.dir/src/mesh3d.F90.o <br/>
[  2%] Building Fortran object _deps/xmlf90-build/CMakeFiles/xmlf90-lib.dir/src/sax/m_sax_elstack.f90.o <br/>
[  2%] Building Fortran object _deps/xmlf90-build/CMakeFiles/xmlf90-lib.dir/src/wxml/m_wxml_core.f90.o <br/>
[  2%] Building Fortran object _deps/xmlf90-build/CMakeFiles/xmlf90-lib.dir/src/dom/m_dom_namednodemap.f90.o <br/>
[  2%] Building Fortran object _deps/xmlf90-build/CMakeFiles/xmlf90-lib.dir/src/dom/m_dom_nodelist.f90.o <br/>
[  2%] Building Fortran object _deps/xmlf90-build/CMakeFiles/xmlf90-lib.dir/src/dom/m_dom_document.f90.o <br/>
[  2%] Building Fortran object _deps/xmlf90-build/CMakeFiles/xmlf90-lib.dir/src/sax/m_xml_error.f90.o <br/>
[  2%] Building Fortran object _deps/libgridxc-build/CMakeFiles/libgridxc-lib.dir/src/moreParallelSubs.F90.o <br/>
[  2%] Building Fortran object _deps/xmlf90-build/CMakeFiles/xmlf90-lib.dir/src/wxml/m_wxml_overloads.f90.o <br/>
[  2%] Building Fortran object _deps/xmlf90-build/CMakeFiles/xmlf90-lib.dir/src/dom/m_dom_node.f90.o <br/>
[  2%] Building Fortran object _deps/xmlf90-build/CMakeFiles/xmlf90-lib.dir/src/sax/m_sax_entities.f90.o <br/>
[  2%] Building Fortran object _deps/xmlf90-build/CMakeFiles/xmlf90-lib.dir/src/wxml/xmlf90_wxml.f90.o <br/>
[  2%] Building Fortran object _deps/xmlf90-build/CMakeFiles/xmlf90-lib.dir/src/dom/m_dom_attribute.f90.o <br/>
[  2%] Building Fortran object _deps/xmlf90-build/CMakeFiles/xmlf90-lib.dir/src/sax/m_sax_fsm.f90.o <br/>
[  2%] Building Fortran object _deps/libgridxc-build/CMakeFiles/libgridxc-lib.dir/src/ggaxc.F90.o <br/>
[  2%] Building Fortran object _deps/xmlf90-build/CMakeFiles/xmlf90-lib.dir/src/cml/m_wstml.f90.o <br/>
[  2%] Building Fortran object _deps/xmlf90-build/CMakeFiles/xmlf90-lib.dir/src/dom/m_dom_element.f90.o <br/>
[  2%] Building Fortran object _deps/libgridxc-build/CMakeFiles/libgridxc-lib.dir/src/chkgmx.F90.o <br/>
[  2%] Building Fortran object _deps/libgridxc-build/CMakeFiles/libgridxc-lib.dir/src/radfft.F90.o <br/>
[  2%] Building Fortran object _deps/xmlf90-build/CMakeFiles/xmlf90-lib.dir/src/sax/m_xml_parser.f90.o <br/>
[  2%] Building Fortran object _deps/libgridxc-build/CMakeFiles/libgridxc-lib.dir/src/fft3d.F90.o <br/>
/home/boubacart/SIESTA/siesta-5.0.0/_build/_deps/libgridxc-src/src/fft3d.F90:234.25: <br/>

  call c_f_pointer(c_loc(aDat(:,:,:,1)),aux1,[aMesh(1)*aMesh(2)*aMesh(3)])
                         1
Warning: Array section in 'c_loc' call at (1) <br/>
/home/boubacart/SIESTA/siesta-5.0.0/_build/_deps/libgridxc-src/src/fft3d.F90:235.25: <br/>

  call c_f_pointer(c_loc(aDat(:,:,:,2)),aux2,[aMesh(1)*aMesh(2)*aMesh(3)])
                         1
Warning: Array section in 'c_loc' call at (1) <br/>
/home/boubacart/SIESTA/siesta-5.0.0/_build/_deps/libgridxc-src/src/fft3d.F90:249.28: <br/>

     call c_f_pointer(c_loc(aDat(:,:,i3,1)),aux1,[aMesh(1)*aMesh(2)]) <br/>
                            1
Warning: Array section in 'c_loc' call at (1) <br/>
/home/boubacart/SIESTA/siesta-5.0.0/_build/_deps/libgridxc-src/src/fft3d.F90:250.28: <br/>

     call c_f_pointer(c_loc(aDat(:,:,i3,2)),aux2,[aMesh(1)*aMesh(2)]) <br/>
                            1
Warning: Array section in 'c_loc' call at (1) <br/>
/home/boubacart/SIESTA/siesta-5.0.0/_build/_deps/libgridxc-src/src/fft3d.F90:263.25: <br/>

  call c_f_pointer(c_loc(aDat(:,:,:,1)),aux1,[aMesh(1)*aMesh(2)*aMesh(3)]) <br/>
                         1
Warning: Array section in 'c_loc' call at (1) <br/>
/home/boubacart/SIESTA/siesta-5.0.0/_build/_deps/libgridxc-src/src/fft3d.F90:264.25: <br/>

  call c_f_pointer(c_loc(aDat(:,:,:,2)),aux2,[aMesh(1)*aMesh(2)*aMesh(3)]) <br/>
                         1
Warning: Array section in 'c_loc' call at (1) <br/>
[  2%] Building Fortran object _deps/libgridxc-build/CMakeFiles/libgridxc-lib.dir/src/debugxc.F90.o <br/>
[  2%] Building Fortran object _deps/xmlf90-build/CMakeFiles/xmlf90-lib.dir/src/cml/m_wcml.f90.o <br/>
[  2%] Building Fortran object _deps/xmlf90-build/CMakeFiles/xmlf90-lib.dir/src/dom/m_dom_utils.f90.o <br/>
[  2%] Building Fortran object _deps/libgridxc-build/CMakeFiles/libgridxc-lib.dir/src/vv_vdwxc.F90.o <br/>
[  3%] Building Fortran object _deps/libgridxc-build/CMakeFiles/libgridxc-lib.dir/src/fftr.F90.o <br/>
[  3%] Building Fortran object _deps/xmlf90-build/CMakeFiles/xmlf90-lib.dir/src/sax/xmlf90_sax.f90.o <br/>
[  3%] Building Fortran object _deps/xmlf90-build/CMakeFiles/xmlf90-lib.dir/src/dom/m_dom_parse.f90.o <br/>
[  3%] Building Fortran object _deps/xmlf90-build/CMakeFiles/xmlf90-lib.dir/src/xpath/m_xpath_api.f90.o <br/>
[  3%] Building Fortran object _deps/xmlf90-build/CMakeFiles/xmlf90-lib.dir/src/dom/xmlf90_dom.f90.o <br/>
[  3%] Building Fortran object _deps/libgridxc-build/CMakeFiles/libgridxc-lib.dir/src/vdwxc.F90.o <br/>
[  4%] Building Fortran object _deps/xmlf90-build/CMakeFiles/xmlf90-lib.dir/src/xpath/xmlf90_xpath.f90.o <br/>
[  4%] Building Fortran object _deps/xmlf90-build/CMakeFiles/xmlf90-lib.dir/src/cml/xmlf90_cml.f90.o <br/>
[  4%] Linking Fortran static library libxmlf90.a <br/>
[  4%] Built target xmlf90-lib <br/>
[  4%] Building Fortran object _deps/libgridxc-build/CMakeFiles/libgridxc-lib.dir/src/xcmod.F90.o <br/>
[  4%] Building Fortran object _deps/libgridxc-build/CMakeFiles/libgridxc-lib.dir/src/cellxc.F90.o <br/>
[  4%] Building Fortran object _deps/libgridxc-build/CMakeFiles/libgridxc-lib.dir/src/atomxc.F90.o <br/>
[  4%] Building Fortran object _deps/libgridxc-build/CMakeFiles/libgridxc-lib.dir/src/gridxc.F90.o <br/>
[  4%] Linking Fortran static library libgridxc.a <br/>
[  4%] Built target libgridxc-lib <br/>
gmake: *** [all] Error 2 <br/>

Time spent in user mode   (CPU seconds) : 16.658s <br/>
Time spent in kernel mode (CPU seconds) : 1.717s <br/>
Total time                              : 0:06.99s <br/>
CPU utilisation (percentage)            : 262.6% <br/>
Times the process was swapped           : 0 <br/>
Times of major page faults              : 0 <br/>
Times of minor page faults              : 865512 <br/>
<br/>========================================================

Did anyone encounter a similar issue? any ideas to solve this?
Thanks

Your gcc and gfortran are both very old; the most recent gfortran version is 14.1 for example. This seems to be a case of Fortran feature used by mctc-lib not being supported by the old gfortran compiler.

Thanks Tyberius

TL;DR: Please update your compiler suite (GCC) to a more modern compiler suite (e.g., the latest version of GCC).

I think you already have a couple of replies to your question that point you in the same, correct direction, one in the comment above by user Tyberius, and another one on the SIESTA mailing list where you asked the same question.  But let me reply with a bit more detail:

You are using a very old compiler suite: GCC 4.8.5 was released in June 2015, 9 years ago, and it's a point release update of GCC 4.8.0, released in March 2013.

When compiling one of the SIESTA dependencies, the Modular computation tool chain library (mctc-lib), your compiler fails because one of the files, error.f90, defines a Fortran type that contains a deferred-length character component.

This is a Fortran language feature introduced in the Fortran 2003 standard (ISO/IEC 1539-1:2004(E), J3 draft).

According to the Chart of Fortran 2003 Features supported by GNU Fortran, see the "Allocatable character length" row, gfortran 4.8.5 does not support that feature: while deferred-length character variables were supported since GCC 4.6, they were only supported as type components starting from GCC 4.9.

CMake is trying to compile mctc-lib because you are compiling SIESTA with support for DFTD3 dispersion corrections, and this functionality requires the mctc-lib library.

In order to compile SIESTA with support for DFTD3 dispersion corrections, you need to use a more modern compiler.  Nowadays there are a few freely available Fortran compilers, and getting to use them is not particularly hard (you may download pre-compiled binaries, run an official docker container, etc.)

Fortran compilers are constantly developed. More modern versions of Fortran compilers not only provide support for a wider range of Fortran language features, they also introduce support for wider ranges of new instruction set extensions (so that they can fully exploit all the compute power of new computer processors) and optimisation enhancements.  Therefore, using old compilers is usually a bad idea.

DFTD3 support, whilst enabled by default, is actually an optional feature of SIESTA.

If you really, really cannot get a more modern compiler, and you are going to run SIESTA on a very old processor, and you don't need the DFTD3 dispersion corrections functionality, then you could try to see what happens if you disable the DFTD3 functionality by passing the following option to cmake in the configuration step: -DSIESTA_WITH_DFTD3=OFF.  Still, it is quite likely that you will get stuck at another point of the compilation because of another language feature that was missing in GCC 4.8.



Thanks jme52 for this extended and useful response. I will try to see if a more recent gcc compiler can be installed and see what happens.
